# AES Decryption - Porting code from C# to Java

Tags: c#, java, encryption, aes

I am trying to port the following code from C# into Java. I have made multiple attempts to try and decrypt my encrypted data and I get gibberish every time. The code below uses the org.bouncycastle library and unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a 1-1 mapping between the C# code and the Java code.

I basically know three things:

- byte[] file - This contains my encrypted file. Usually a pretty large array of bytes.
- byte[] padding - It is 32**bytes** every time and it seems that the first 16 bytes of this are used as the IV.
- byte[] aesKey - It is 32**bytes** every time and I do not know how exactly the C# code is using this array.

**Original C# Code**

```
    private byte[] decryptmessage(byte[] cmessage, byte[] iVector, byte[] m_Key)
    {
        {
        //// randomly generated number acts as inetialization vector
        m_IV = new byte[16];
        Array.Copy(iVector, 0, m_IV, 0, 16);

        // GenerateAESKey();
        KeyParameter aesKeyParam = ParameterUtilities.CreateKeyParameter("AES", m_Key);
        ParametersWithIV aesIVKeyParam = new ParametersWithIV(aesKeyParam, m_IV);

        IBufferedCipher cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
        cipher.Init(false, aesIVKeyParam);
        return cipher.DoFinal(cmessage);
        }
    }
```

**My attempt in Java**

```
  private static byte[] decryptMessage(byte[] file, byte[] iVector, byte[] aesKey) throws Exception {
    IvParameterSpec spec = new IvParameterSpec(Arrays.copyOfRange(iVector, 0, 16));
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOfRange(aesKey, 0, 16), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
    return cipher.doFinal(file);
  }
```

P.S: This is the final step of decryption. Before all this I had to take out some initial set of bytes from my encrypted file and decrypt them using an RSA private key to get this AES key.

If someone has a link / document I can read that properly explains the whole process of using AES to encrypt a file, then using RSA on the key and iv to the begining of the encrypted file, I will be extremely happy. I have just been staring at the C# code, I'd like to see something with pictures.

EDIT: Bytes not bits.

EDIT2: Renamed padding to iVector for consistency and correctness.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at bouncycastle

Comment: I did not find anything useful there except for the Java API and the C# API. I've done a lot of looking around, anything in particular you want me to look at?

Comment: I guess *padding* and *aesKey* are 32 bytes (not bits). And why did you call the second parameter *padding* when in fact it has nothing to do with padding, but is the initialization vector. Why not call the parameters the same as in the C# code? (Okay, maybe not m_Key which is reserved for member variables.)

Comment: You are correct BYTES. Fixing. And the original code called it padding, the function for decryption renamed the 'padding' variable to iVector. I retained the original name for my method. I'll just fix it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C# code, you initialize the key with 256 bits (32 bytes) and thus get AES-256. In the Java code, you only use 128 bit (16 bytes) and get AES-128.

So the fix is probably:

```
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");
```

You might then find that Java doesn't want to use 256 bit keys (for legal reason). You then have to intall the [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html).

Comment: Let me try JCE. Let's hope the solution is that simple!

Comment: YEP! I was only using the first 16 bytes because trying all 32 gave me a key length error. This works and also makes me feel good about myself. Thanks!